# Using "a href" inside echo

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to print a list of links, this means I need to use a href in the 3rd line, but I don't know how the syntax should be in this situation. Also, the link is a PHP variable.

```
$sql = mysql_query("select nm_linha from linhas where cidades_origem like '%$cod_cidades%'");
while($exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
echo $exibe['nm_linha'] .'<br>';
}
```

Comment: This is [HTML 101](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperlink)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sql = mysql_query("select nm_linha from linhas where cidades_origem like '%$cod_cidades%'");
while($exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
echo '<a href='".$exibe['nm_linha']."'>'.$exibe['nm_linha'].'</a><br>';
}
```

this is going to list the links as well as , on clicking it is redirected to th respective link.
try this.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $sql = mysql_query("select nm_linha from linhas where cidades_origem like '%$cod_cidades%'");
while($exibe = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
echo "<a href='link.html'>".$exibe['nm_linha'] ."</a><br>";
}
```